# Why does setting the position of the x label shift the label for this semilogyaxis in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I have two plots with the same line; one is plotted on a standard scale, one is plotted on a semi-log y scale. The second plot has the x-axis label shifted vertically quite substantially. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ylabel={$p$},
        xlabel={$v$},
        x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}},
        y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, rotate=270,},
    ]
        \addplot+[no markers, domain=2.75:8] {114.795/x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\[10mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        ylabel={$p$},
        xlabel={$v$},
        x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}},
        y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, rotate=270,},
    ]
        \addplot+[no markers, domain=2.75:8] {114.795/x};
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: problem plots]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logarithmis axes have the origin at zero (see keys `log origin`). So label is shifted to the invisible origin at `1`. As a verification, if I increase the domain to `domain=2.75:1000`, I get

[image]

Instead use another anchor (or relative to that) of the `current axis` node, for example,

```
    x label style={at={(current axis.south east)}},
```

gives

[image]

Comment: This is especially effective if you set `xtick=\empty`, then it looks the same as `current axis.right of origin`. Thanks!